# Retrieve object executed via ExecutorService.submit

Tags: submit, return, runnable, executorservice, callable

I have an ExecutorService that runs several solvers in parallel. Each solver modifies several internal variables which value must be returned.
It is not possible to encapsulate all the variables in a class to be returned via a callable object for compatibility issues. Therefore, make the solvers either callable or runnable does not make any difference in my case, as I cannot retrieve all the variables I need.

I considered following two options:

1. Each solver access a synchronized class and writes its values there.
2. Access the objects (solvers) that have been submitted by the executor in order to get their variables via get methods.

I prefer the second option, but I don't find the way to gain access to the objects submitted.

Any suggestion (for any of the options)?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't elaborate on the "compatibility issues", so I can only suggest a general solution for what you described.

Since you use `ExecutorService`, I believe that you use `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or its subclass) as implementation of that interface. If that's the case, I suggest overriding `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` method. It's called after any submitted `Runnable` has completed it's execution. Its default implementation is empty.

Your implementation should follow these steps:

1. Check if `t != null`. If so, process `Throwable` `t` which caused a solver to abort.
2. Check the type of `r` and if you recognize it, retrieve its results. Of course, it will be simpler if all your solvers have a common API.
3. Store results somewhere.

But look out - `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()` is called from the thread that ran the `Runnable` `r`, so the 3rd step will most likely need to be synchronized.

Putting it all together, your code can look like this:

```
if (t != null) {
    // handle t
} else {
    Solver solver = (Solver)r;
    Results results = solver.getResults();
    synchronized (allSolutions) {
        allSolutions.addResults(results);
    }
}
```